# how to take some parts of String with certain pattern

Tags: pattern-matching, string-manipulation

I have the large number of files in which the file's names follow certain pattern. for example here are names of two files

```
name1="event_No. 2_20140311_910_914.jpg"
name2="event_No. 403_20140311_230727_230731.jpg"
```

I need to extract the last two numbers of the names to get something like this (String or Expression, it does not matter):

```
{"910","914"}
{"230727","230731"}
```

I tried StringTake but it is not supporting Rules and patterns.

can any one suggest some way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
StringCases[{name1, name2}, DigitCharacter ..][[All, -2 ;;]]
```

> ```
> {{"910", "914"}, {"230727", "230731"}}
> ```

For fun or interest, also:

```
With[{SR = StringReverse},
  StringCases[{name1, name2} // SR, DigitCharacter .., 2] // SR
]
```

> ```
> {{"914", "910"}, {"230731", "230727"}}
> ```

Comment: Thanks a lot Mr.Wizard. I am impressed with your knowledge of Mathematica.

Comment: @Algohi You're welcome, and thank you. :-)

Answer (score 2):

It is really straight forward when you use `StringCases`.

```
StringCases[{name1, name2}, 
 start__ ~~ "_" ~~ s1 : NumberString ~~ "_" ~~ s2 : NumberString ~~ ".jpg" :> {s1, s2}]

(* {{{"910", "914"}}, {{"230727", "230731"}}} *)
```